# Dell XPS 13 9310 sleep mode issues

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, xps

It is known (from several forums) that the Dell XPS 13 9130 **does not support "deep sleep"**. Whether this issue can be fixed (i.e. enabling this option) by code a new BIOS version is not clear to me.

Anyhow, with Dell BIOS v 2.2.0 and UBUNTU 20.04, I have this annoying problem that might be fixed directly:

**When entering sleep mode with WIFI on, I get a huge battery power loss (up to 20% power gone within 4 hours).**

If I enter sleep after shutting off the wifi service, there is only a moderate (though noticeable and annoying) power loss.

*Any idea how to solve this problem?*

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu yourself on this computer or did it come pre-installed with Ubuntu from the Dell factory (the developer edition)? In case it is the later, did you try Dell support?

Comment: Try to disable both "Sign of Life" options in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a common problem with dell xps. The 'deep sleep' mode is not available in the firmware of the XPS series. It is discussed more in detail in the link below. Though no solution is mentioned by Dell, which is quite disappointing.

https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-9310-Ubuntu-deep-sleep-missing/td-p/7734008

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts to get help from Dell support and forums, all of which were basically useless, I decided to install a fresh KUBUNTU 21.04 from a USB stick. This worked out very well for me.